# Where does this equation come from and the reason behind it to a model exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function, nonlinear-optimization, regression

To model data based on the exponential equation

$$ y=Ae^{Bx} $$

On the website https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html

In equation (5)

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i\left(\ln{\left(y_i\right)}-a-{bx}_i\right)^2} \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space  \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space     (5) $$

where

$$ \ln{\left(A\right)}=a $$

$$ B=b $$

It says this sum should be minimized. It works better than the linearizing the data and doing linear regression for the equation below.

$$ \ln(y)=\ln(A)+Bx $$

I know that this works better but what is the justification for the use of equation (5) or how was it derived?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113620/why-is-there-more-weight-on-smaller-y-values-in-transformed-linear-regression-as), I showed that, if you express the residue as
$$r_i=\log(\hat y_i)-\log( y_i)$$ assuming small errors, you have
$$r_i \sim \frac{\hat y_i-y_i }{y_i }$$ which explains that the linearization leads to the minimization of the sum of the squares of *relative* errors.

So, if now, you express the residue as
$$r_i=y_i \Big[\log(\hat y_i)-\log( y_i)\Big]$$ with the same assumptions, you have
$$r_i \sim y_i \times \frac{\hat y_i-y_i }{y_i }=\hat y_i-y_i$$ which makes that this weighting factor leads to something extremely close to the minimization of the sum of the squares of *absolute* errors.

Comment: If we are finding the sum of the square residuals, wouldn't the equation have a yi^2 instead of just a yi infront of the residual?

Comment: @RICEL123. We minimize $\text{SSQ}=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^\color{red}{2}$